# Container height Animation starts from the middle

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

The Flutter `Container` height animation starts from the middle, but I need it to start from the bottom here is my code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CorrectWrongOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool _isCorrect;
  final VoidCallback _onTap;
  final double percentR;
  final double percentW;

  CorrectWrongOverlay(
      this._isCorrect, this.percentR, this.percentW, this._onTap);

  @override
  State createState() => CorrectWrongOverlayState();
}

class CorrectWrongOverlayState extends State<CorrectWrongOverlay>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _iconAnimation;
  AnimationController _iconAnimationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _iconAnimationController = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    _iconAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _iconAnimationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    _iconAnimationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _iconAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.black54,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => widget._onTap(),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 200.0 * _iconAnimation.value,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to achieve this kind of UI with height grow animations in Flutter I want the animations to start from the bottom but it starts from the center of the container and animated it both side.

[image: Please take a look at the Image]

Answer (score 2):

to start scale animation from certain points. You can wrap your Container with `Align` widget and give certain start positions with simplicty.

define your controller and animation variables;

```
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> tween;
```

init them in initState method;

```
   @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800));
     tween = Tween<double>(begin:0,end:1).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn));
     animationController.addListener(() {
       setState(() {});
     });
}
```

then in build method or where ever you add use return Widget like below;

```
Widget animatedContainer(){
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,// .topCenter, .topLeft, .bottomLeft, bottomCenter...etc
    child: Container(
      width: (size.width * tween.value).abs(),
      height: (200 *tween.value).abs(),
      color:Colors.red
      ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **TweenMax for Flutter** package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/tweenmax

Here is an example: https://github.com/mrgoonie/flutter_tweenmax/blob/master/lib/screens/animated_column_chart.dart

Click on the bottom button to animate those bars.

[image]

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you're animating it once and don't require advanced animation control, then you don't even need to keep track of `AnimationController` yourself. Just use [`TweenAnimationBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html), pass to it your tween, duration and curve, and let it animate widget for you:

```dart
Widget _animatedBarWidget(Widget barWidget) => TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
  tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  builder: (BuildContext context, double value, Widget? child) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      heightFactor: value,
      child: child!,
    );
  },
  child: barWidget,
);
```

Then, just call

```dart
_animatedBarWidget(Container(width: 80.0, height: 200.0, color:Colors.red));
```